Using \RenewDocumentCommand to redefine \theequation label cases incorrect referencing

Using \renewcommand solves the issue, but is this a bug in \RenewDocumentCommand?
\documentclass[11pt,openany]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{empty}}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{amsmath}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\RenewDocumentCommand{\theequation}{}{\arabic{equation}}
%\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}

% END_FOLD

\usepackage{hyperref}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\hypersetup{linkcolor=DodgerBlue3, colorlinks=true}

% END_FOLD

\begin{document}

\chapter{Text}

\begin{alignat}{4}
    V
    &\propto I
    &&
    \label{eq:V_prop_I}
    \\
    V
    &= R I
    &&
    \label{eq:V_IR}
\end{alignat}

This should reference \parbox[l]{3em}{Eq. 1} \ref{eq:V_prop_I}

\smallskip

This should reference \parbox[l]{3em}{Eq. 2} \ref{eq:V_IR}

\chapter{Text}

\begin{alignat}{4}
    V
    &\propto I
    &&
    \label{eq:V_prop_I}
    \\
    V
    &= R I
    &&
    \label{eq:V_IR}
\end{alignat}

This should reference \parbox[l]{3em}{Eq. 1} \ref{eq:V_prop_I}

\smallskip

This should reference \parbox[l]{3em}{Eq. 2} \ref{eq:V_IR}


\end{document}


\the...counter commands have to expand to the print form of the counter, but \RenewDocumentCommand defines a \protected command in which expansion is suppressed, so use \renewcommand or \RenewExpandableDocumentCommand

No bug, but expected and desired feature.
\NewDocumentCommand is targeted to address a couple of features:

parsing complex series of argument types (optional arguments, delimited arguments, variants and so on);

making the command robust, that is, unchanged in situations where writing to auxiliary files (and a few others).


Commands such as \the<counter>, in your case \theequation, mustn't be robust so \arabic{equation} is actually expanded when the annotation in the auxiliary file is made.
Here's a minimal example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\theequation}{}{\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
a+b=c \label{c}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
a+b=d \label{d}
\end{equation}

\end{document}

If you LaTeX this once, the .aux file will be
\relax 
\newlabel{c}{{\theequation }{1}{}{}{}}
\newlabel{d}{{\theequation }{1}{}{}{}}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}

Can you see where the problem is? Let's make a more interesting MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\theequation}{}{\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}

\ref{c} and \ref{d}

\begin{equation}
a+b=c \label{c}
\end{equation}

\ref{c} and \ref{d}

\begin{equation}
a+b=d \label{d}
\end{equation}

\ref{c} and \ref{d}

\end{document}


Now you should see what the problem is: \ref{c} becomes \theequation and not 1 as it should. So the first pair of references yield 0 because that's the current value of equation and so on.
Commands such as \theequation should always be redefined with \renewcommand. You might use \RenewExpandableDocumentCommand, but it just adds some layers around a simple redefinition to \arabic{equation}.
